# Adding help to the user defined functions in TCL

Tags: tcl

how can i add some kind of help to the user defined functions in TCL

Supposing if i have a function called runtest {ip_address test_time},
How to describe what the test or procedure is about in the TCL_shell?

How can i specify the information to the user, if he types in function_name --help in the TCL shell the user should be able to know what the function does and what exactly are the parameters.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that it is not part of the language, it is fairly easy to implement something that adds this functionality to pre-existing functions. The only caveat being that the function then cannot take the string `--help` as a valid argument since that argument will trigger the feature.

Here's one simple implementation:

```
# Lets call the feature "document". As in, add documentation:
proc document {procname text} {
  rename $procname __$procname
  proc $procname args [string map [list %TEXT% $text %PROC% $procname] {
    if {$args == "--help"} {
      puts {%TEXT%}
    } else {
      set script [linsert $args 0 __%PROC%]
      return [uplevel 1 $script]
    }
  }]
}
```

What this does is to override the function (by renaming and then declaring another function of the same name) and see if the function is called with the argument `--help`. If it is it prints the documentation otherwise it executes the original function. Just be careful not to call this twice on the same function (it can be modified for it to work though).

So you can do things like:

```
proc foo {} {puts 2}
document foo {Prints the number 2.}
```

Now if you call:

```
foo --help
```

and it would output:

```
Prints the number 2.
```

Comment: Should work. Tested it on my machine before posting it here. What tcl version are you using?

Comment: It would be better with `return [uplevel 1 [list __%PROC% {*}$args]]` as that lets the proc think it isn't wrapped. Or `tailcall __%PROC% {*}$args` in 8.6.

Comment: It works for Tclsh 8.5, but for 8.4, got *extra characters after close-brace* because you are using the {*} construct, which is introduced in 8.5.

Comment: Thanks Donal, modified with your suggestion. Should even work with 8.4 now.

Comment: With 8.4, you _cannot_ use `{*}`. Scripts with that in are not back-portable at all. Mind you, my preferred fix for that is to stop using 8.4 or before…

Comment: Arrgh.. missed that. Fixed now. Man, didn't think I'd have to debug and maintain this thing before I posted it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to touch the existing procedures:

```
proc help {procname} {
  puts $::helptext($procname)
}

proc addhelp {procname text} {
  set ::helptext($procname) $text
}

addhelp foo "this is the help text for procedure foo"

help foo
```

Comment: +1 This is a cleaner implementation and close to what we use at work.

Comment: I can see improvements, such as checking that a procedure actually exists, pulling out the argument list for the proc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without redefining the `proc` command, you cannot. Ie, that functionality is not built into the language, but would be possible to add if you so wished.

I will note that adding the capability yourself, while possible, is probably beyond the difficulty where it's worth doing, especially for someone that isn't intimately familiar with the language. That being said, you can check the [tclers wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) for a preexisting implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer to put help in a separate file (e.g., as HTML) which lets me browse it in another window. There are so many ways you can do that while still keeping the docs with the code, such as through [doxygen](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17438).

There are also a number of ways of doing interactive documentation, several of which are described in [the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10793); it would seem to me that some of the techniques mentioned on that page (together with @slebetman's answer) would give you what you wanted. (I think it would be easier to have a separate `help` command as that would avoid having the help syntax interfere with the command, but that's your call.)